# Collapse cell group to only show the output, when there are multiple output cells?

Tags: front-end

I can double click on Output cell to collapse the input cell, but this doesn't appear to work when there are multiple output cells (due to multiple `Print` statements), as this action is overriden by "collapse cell group" functionality.

Is there a workaround?

Example

```
Print[1]
Print[2]
```

I want to collapse the "Print"s and only see what's been printed

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the cells within the cell group you wish to show:

[image]

now double-click on any of the blue-shaded cell brackets and it should collapse with only those visible:

[image]

Comment: so this generally works, but not when you have mutiple print statements, added an example